# Moving Emails to Public Folder using Dynamic Paths

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

In our Corporate environment we have a Mailbox (not the default inbox) with many sub folders. We also have a Public Folder which is an exact mirror of the Mailbox folder structure.

I am trying to detect the path of a selected email and move that email to its mirrored folder in the Public Folders.

I would say 95% of this code is correct but I am left with an Outlook error message "Can't move the items."

The code is supposed to do the following:
1. detects the current folder of the selected email(s)
2. converts the MAPIFolder into a path string
3. shortens the string to remove the root Mailbox directory structure
4. adds the remaining string onto the root directory structure of the public folder
5. converts the resulting path back into a MAPIFolder
6. move the selected email(s) to the mirrored folder in the Public Folders

```vb
Sub PublicFolderAutoArchive()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim currentNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim wipFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim pubFolder As String
    Dim wipFolderString As String
    Dim Messages As Selection
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim Msg As MailItem
    Dim Proceed As VbMsgBoxResult

    Set olApp = Application
    Set currentNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set wipFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set Messages = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    ' Destination root directory'
    ' Tried with both "\\Public Folders" and "Public Folders" .. neither worked
    pubFolder = "\\Public Folders\All Public Folders\InboxMirror"

    ' wipFolder.FolderPath Could be any folder in our mailbox such as:  
    ' "\\Mailbox - Corporate Account\Inbox\SubFolder1\SubFolder2"
    ' however, the \\Mailbox - Corporate Account\Inbox\" part is 
    ' static and never changes so the variable below removes the static
    ' section, then the remainder of the path is added onto the root 
    ' of the public folder path which is an exact mirror of the inbox.
    ' This is to allow a dynamic Archive system where the destination 
    'path matches the source path except for the root directory.
    wipFolderString = Right(wipFolder.FolderPath, Len(wipFolder.FolderPath) - 35)

    ' tried with and without the & "\" ... neither worked
    Set objFolder = GetFolder(pubFolder & wipFolderString & "\")

    If Messages.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each itm In Messages
        If itm.Class = olMail Then
            Proceed = MsgBox("Are you sure you want archive the message to the Public Folder?", _
            vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm Archive")
            If Proceed = vbYes Then
                Set Msg = itm
                Msg.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetFolder(strFolderPath As String) As MAPIFolder
  ' strFolderPath needs to be something like
  '   "Public Folders\All Public Folders\Company\Sales" or
  '   "Personal Folders\Inbox\My Folder"

  Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim colFolders As Outlook.Folders
  Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim arrFolders() As String
  Dim I As Long
  On Error Resume Next

  strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "/", "\")
  arrFolders() = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
  Set objApp = Application
  Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item(arrFolders(0))
  If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    For I = 1 To UBound(arrFolders)
      Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
      Set objFolder = Nothing
      Set objFolder = colFolders.Item(arrFolders(I))
      If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If

Set GetFolder = objFolder
Set colFolders = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Note: The mailbox above is just an example and is not the actual mailbox name. I used MsgBox to confirm the path string was being joined correctly with all appropriate back slashes and that the Right() function was getting what I needed from the source path.

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but should be something like?

```
set objApp = New Outlook.Application
```

instead of

```
    set objApp = Application
```

Answer (score 0):

From glancing at the code, it appears that your `GetFolder()` implementation doesn't like the double-backslash you're giving at the start of the path.  There's even a comment indicating this at the start of the function.  Try removing those two chars from the front of `pubFolder`.

Alternatively, you could alter `GetFolder` to permit them.  A few lines like this should do the trick.

```
If Left(strFolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
    strFolderPath = Right(strFolderPath, Len(strFolderPath) - 2)
End If
```